# protection from erronous input

Tags: c++, c, error-handling, input

I worked with numbers ( int, float, double, long, unsigned ), but when I put other character to console ( such as `^[[A`, or `*` ). Therefore, my program is crashing

How can I protect my program from this erroneous input ?

Note : I know some library function namely `isdigit` or `isallnum`, but they don't help so much

Comment: can you post the code on how you get user input?

Comment: I take input with cin >>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++ it's possible to do this by filtering the data through a stringstream.  There's a discussion of how to do this [at Stanford's introductory C++ course site](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106l/course-reader/Ch3_Streams.pdf), with full code for reading integers on page 19.  The rest of the chapter is also a good resource in general for how to do I/O in C++, which might also be useful.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this in C as well as C++, is to read all inputs as strings, then parse the string.

This is one reason why you should never use scanf("%d") or cin>>integer for any other purposes than debugging / student / hobbyist programs.

Comment: of course you can use `std::cin >> integer` to read integers from the console.. but you may not forget the correct error handling. On the other side, correct error handling is not possible for erronous input upon a `scanf("%d")`

Comment: simple error handling for std::cin: `if( !(cin >> integerVar) ){ cin.clear(); cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n'); cout<<"Invalid integer input!\n"; }`

Comment: @smerlin- that works, but if you enter something like 137abc it will incorrectly think that you entered the valid number 137 and will leave abc in cin to be read on the next cin read without any prompting.